# Access a property of a DbSet by name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `DbSet<T>`

I want to access one of the properties on it by name.

Is this possible?

I'm basically making a generic function, so that for any DbSet I have, I can specify a column and have it list the values of that column.

You can get the `DbSet` itself from the context by doing `context.Set(T)` but I am not sure about the fields.

Comment: What is the generic context here? Can you show the signature of the method where you want your query to originate (to see what kind of generic type parameter we have) and perhaps a one-line statement using that method and the expected outcome?

Comment: The concept is that I have a table called 'books' and one of the fields is 'author' and I want to perform a search on the 'author' column. I also have lots of other tables that I want to perform the identical search on, so making a generic method where I say give me matching objects eg. `IEnumerable<T>` by matching column `"Author"` or whatever column I specify.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did something similar a while back using reflection.

```
T item = context.Set(T).First();
string propName = "MyProperty";
object value = item.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(item, null);
```

Of course note that you'll either need to cast the values to a specific type manually, or use `ToString`, which should work quite well on all basic types.

This assumes you already have the data from the server, and now need to process it.

**EDIT:**

If you want to create a query, then I found [this](https://entityframework.net/system-linq-dynamic)!

Apparently, what you're looking for is available as part of Entity Framework these days.

An extension method is available which allows you to use `.Select("propertyName")` which returns `IQueriable`. Remember to add `System.Linq.Dynamic` to your `using` section.

You can then create select queries by specifying the name of the parameter.

```
List<object> data = (db.Set<SetType>()
                       .Where("propertyName == @0 && someOtherProperty == @1", propertyValue, someOtherPropertyValue)
                       .Select("propertyName") as IEnumerable<object>).ToList();
```

Comment: Cool, I've just tried this, what do you think the performance implications will be? I assume it will simply generate a single SQL statement so if I wanted to select all entities with a "Name" field of "Hello" then I could just do dbSet.Where(c => c.GetType.....GetValue... == "Hello") and the performance issue would be negligable?

Comment: @SLC I found a solution to your problem - check the updated answer! :)

Comment: Right, I've tried the first bit which looked like it'd work, but LINQ to Entities tries to translate the whole GetType GetProperty thing and fails. I guess because that part needs to be done server-side and only the result should go into LINQ to entities? `dbSet.Where(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(c, null) == someString)`

Comment: @SLC Like I've said, I've edited the answer - check the second part! :)

Comment: I see, I've included the dynamic linq dll into my solution but I am not sure how to do a `where` clause as in my comment above.

Comment: @SLC Check out the sample code provided, it contains a `Where` clause. I've also edited my answer to include a sample `Where`. If you're still having problems, then you need to be more specific

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm either going to go with that or simply just execute the query directly using `.SqlQuery` because there is only so much bending the EF to my will that I can do! :)

Comment: The MSDN link has expired :/

Comment: @chakeda It was a blog post, but... yeah, it's outdated. I'll replace it with something working.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this article on Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Using the provided code, I was able to write a LINQ to Entities query like this:

```
var query = context.Set(Type.GetType("Person")).Select("Name");
```

Comment: Is `context.Set()` not available in .Net Core?